# Axios call returning 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, axios

I was given an API from our API team, and when I tested it in SoapUI and in Swagger, I was able to return results. I also get the same values in the java logging from the API.

Here is an example of the return payload:

```
{
   "labId": 1,
   "id": 444,
   "name": "Accelerator Fluid",
   "description": "Accelerator",
   "accNumber": "55555",
   "solvent": "Water"
}
```

The problem comes when I try to make the call in Axios. Rather than returning the values, I only get "undefined".

I have used this Axios call for multiple pages and have never had an issue with it until now.

**Here is how I am handling the Axios API call:**

```
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({} as any);

const detailsURL = environmentURL + '/resources/{labId}/{id}?id=' + selectedRecord.id + '&labId=' + labIdNum;

// const detailsURL = environmentURL + '/resources/' + labIdNum + '/' + selectedRecord.id; 
// the above URL does not work (404 error)


  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`${detailsUrl}`);
        setValues(res.data.data);
        setCallStatus(res.data.status);
        console.log('API Response Status: Success');
      } catch (error) {
        setValues(error.response.data);
        console.log('API Response Status: Error');
        console.error(error.message);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log('Values: ', values);
```

The console.log from my Axio call is says, 'API Response Status: Success', but the values are undefined.

When I console.log the detailsURL I get something like this:  *http://localhost:8080/resources/{labId}/{id}?id=444&labId=1*
I can paste this same URL into SoapUI and Swagger and both will return the record as intended, but if I rework the URL to be something like this:   *http://localhost:8080/resources/1/444*  I just get a 404 error.

Can someone please clue me in on what is going on?  Why does the URL of the API work in SoapUI and Swagger to return the record, but return undefined in Axios?

Comment: Do you specifically mean that `res.data.data` has an `undefined` value?  If that's the case, what does `res.data` have when you log it to the console?

Comment: Your return payload did not have data so according to @David you need to use setValues(res.data)

Comment: You guys nailed it!.  I guess our team wrote the API differently than the rest of the APIs for this project, so instead of 'res.data.data'  I needed 'res.data'.  SO simple, and I just missed it.